# Kubernetes centralized logging using EFK

Tags: logging, kubernetes, fluentd, efk

I am new to kubernetes and centralized logging. I have installed EFK on my cluster from [kubernetes repository](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch) and I deleted the flowing code from fluentd-es-ds.yaml file:

```
nodeSelector:
  beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready: "true"
```

I installed [counter pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) that logs at sout but I can't find the logs in kibana. Why did fluend didn't find the logs? Where does kubernetes store the logs?

I must mention that I have my cluster running on centos machines.

EDIT

I have figured out what the problem is. I have systemd on the machines and my logs are written in journald. I found out that all the logs are in "/run/log/journal" on master node. Do you know how I can change this so that logs can be found on every machine where the pods are running? Or if you know a way to get logs from journald using fluentd?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/ ?

Comment: Yes this is the documentation from where I installed counter pod. But I still don't understand where logs for pods are stored and I can't figure out how this works with fluentd. Thanks!

Comment: Logs from stdout are captured by the docker daemon, if ur using docker.  Fluentd basically use in_tail to read those docker logs and forwards them to elasticsearch if configured.  Check out the fluentd-es-config.yaml file to see how fluentd is configured.

Comment: And where are docker logs stored? I didn't find anything in "/var/log" or "/var/lib/docker". I don't know where to search for logs.